# how to insert a piece of code to a larger code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file which contains 1000 words and a folder (the name of this folder is "train") that contains 7 other sub folders and each sub folder contains 8 files. I have to check if these 1000 words are in the train folder. if they exist, it appends +1 to the list, else it should append -1 to the list. At last it should produce a vector that contains 1000 of +1 or -1. the code I wrote produces more than 1000 elements and printing doesn't stop. It's because I have to find unique words first and check these 1000 words in them. but I don't know how to insert the code of finding unique words to the code I wrote it already.

hint: I extracted these 1000 words from the train folder. they are 1000 most common words of this folder. (the language is persian)

```
import os


def c (folder_path):
    t=[]    
    k=[]
    uniqueWords = [] 
    for folder in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)):
        folder_path1 = os.path.join(folder_path, folder)
         for folder1 in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path1)):
             file=os.path.join(folder_path1, folder1)
             text = open(file,encoding="utf-8") 
             text=text.read().split()
             t=text+t
             with open ("c:/python34/1000CommonWords.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f1:
             f1=f1.readlines()
              for j in f1:
                  if j in uniqueWords:
                      k.append (+1)
                  else:
                      k.append (-1)
              print (k)
```

the code for finding unique words:

```
for i in t:
     if not i in uniqueWords:
         uniqueWords.append(i)
```

Comment: Mh... this code should not work: `f1=f1.read().split()` -- on the first iteration you are replacing `f1` with a list, and on the second iteration you are calling `list.read()`, which should result in an exception. But you are not mentioning any exception in your question, so I assume that the code you are running is not the code you have posted

Comment: I edited that part. now how can I find unique words in t?

Comment: I can't understand the question. Do you have 56 files in which you are looking for 1000 words? Is the desired result 56 vectors with "+1"/"-1", one for each file and an entry for each word?

Comment: the result must be a vector (a matrix) of 1*1000. It has 1000 +1, -1.

Comment: if I can find unique words of this 56 files, the problem will be solved. how can I find them?

Comment: For every file you open, put their words into a `set`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question title and the "real question" that pops up in the comments are quite different. To find all unique words in all files in subdirectories of a given directory, you should use the handy [os.walk method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), then open all files and collect the words in a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

```
import os

allwords = set()

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):
    print("In path {}: subdirs: {}, files: {}".format(path, dirs, filenames))
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as fileobj:
            for line in fileobj:
                print(line)
                allwords.update(line.split())

print(allwords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function:

```
def unique_words(filename):
    # most of the code in your first example block
    return uniqueWords

uniques = unique_words('...CommonWords.txt')

for i in t:
    if i not in uniques:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
import os

def classification (folder_path):
    t=[]    # opens train
    k=[]
    uniqueWords = []
    for folder in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)):
        folder_path1 = os.path.join(folder_path, folder)
        for folder1 in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path1)):
             file=os.path.join(folder_path1, folder1)
             text = open(file,encoding="utf-8") 
             text=text.read().split()
             t=text+t

             for i in t:
                if not i in uniqueWords:
                    uniqueWords.append(i)
            # return uniqueWords




        with open ("c:/python34/1000CommonWords.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f1:
            f1=f1.read().split()  #extracts the vector
            for j in f1:
                if j in uniqueWords :
                    k.append (+1)
                else:
                    k.append (-1)
                    print (k)
```

Comment: try to use a `dict` instead. `words={}` `if(i in words): words[i] += 1; else: words[i] = 1` then you can process the dict. you can process all files to one dict and handle this (if you got enough ram)